# Can Auras be moved between creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I play [Valeron Warden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Valeron%20Warden) and then play [Knightly Valor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knightly%20Valor), enchanting Valeron Warden. Valeron Warden now has +2/+2 and Vilgilance.  On the next turn, I play [Archangel of Tithes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archangel%20of%20Tithes), a much stronger creature. To make it stronger, can I move the enchantment, Knightly Valor from Valeron Warden and enchant Archangel of Tithes?

All I can find on this is that it must have a target and that it can be sent to the graveyard if the target is sent to the graveyard.

Comment: The thing that *can* move around between creatures, by the way, is [Equipment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+[%22Equipment%22]).

Comment: Nice...negative vote.  For what?

Comment: Asking about downvotes often isn't terribly productive since the user who voted won't be notified about your comment. But my best guess would be lack of research effort (one of the things shown when you hover over the downvote arrow): It's something that's covered in the basic rules, and the Google results for things like "can you move auras mtg" answer this pretty directly

Comment: Then shut the site down since this can all be googled!  LOL - don't do that.  I come to SE when things on a Google search aren't clear to me.  Sorry if this is terribly simplistic to the rest of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot move the enchantment (unless you have a card like [Aura Finesse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aura%20Finesse).  Aura **spells** need a target when they are cast.

> 113.1b Aura spells are always targeted. These are the only permanent spells with targets. An Aura’s target is specified by its enchant
> keyword ability (see rule 702.5, “Enchant”). The target(s) are chosen
> as the spell is cast; see rule 601.2c. An Aura permanent doesn’t
> target anything; only the spell is targeted. (An activated or
> triggered ability of an Aura permanent can also be targeted.)

The target is only chosen when it is cast and is a **spell** (ie. on the stack but before it has resolved and entered the battlefield).  Unless something allows you to move it ([Simic Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simic%20Guildmage), etc.) there is no way for you to cast it again while it is on the battlefield and choose a new target.

Comment: OK...the combination of both 601.2c and 608.2b explicitly state targeting as part of both the casting and resolution of the spell - declaring and verifying a target as legally target-able. This is what Diego was trying to get me to see.  But the rule(s) stating as much are what I was looking for.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli If you have questions like this, the [basic rules](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf) are really much better. There's a brief bit about auras early on in the rules, then the entry for "aura" in the glossary tells you pretty much exactly what it means, and it's all written to be much more understandable than the comprehensive rules.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli Also note that these don't specifically say it *can't* be moved, they just explain that when you cast it you get to attach it to a creature. The reason you can't move it is exactly what diego said: this is all the rules say you can do.

Answer (score 4):

In general once an Aura is enchanting an object it stays enchanting that object. There are no rules that allow you to move Auras from one object to another, therefore you cannot do it.

There are exceptions though, cards like [Simic Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simic%20Guildmage) have the ability to move Auras to different permanents, and [Illusory Gains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusory%20Gains) moves itself whenever a creature enters the battlefield.

Comment: In general I would tend to agree.  But I don't see any rules stating you can't or that once played on a permanent it's locked to that permanent.  If you can show me something like that I'll mark this as the answer. The cards you linked to imply you are correct but not explicit enough for what I'm looking for.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli That isn't how the rule of Magic work. The rules give you permission to do things, since they don't give you permission to move Auras you cannot do so.

Comment: An aura is an enchantment, which works like a spell.  It goes on the stack.  There are other enchantments that state, add one to your mana pool, or add +1/+1 to all creatures under your control.  Knightly Valor says enchant a creature.  It doesn't say once and only once, just like add one to your mana pool is not a one time event.  So this seems like a gray area to me, barring anythig that states otherwise.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli And those work because there are rules saying they do. There is no rule saying you can move an enchantment, therefore you cannot do it. Also, what enchantment are you talking about that adds mana to your mana pool?

Comment: Let's back up a sec...take Simic Guildmage out of the equation - it's a creature not an aura enchantment.  Second, Illusory Gains very first line says "Enchant Creature" - same as Knightly Valor.  Where does it say this is a one time event?  Other enchantments like [Silkwrap](http://tappedout.net/mtg-card/silkwrap/) state when the action triggers.  I'll have to get back with you on the mana adding card, I don't remember it off had and it might be an artifact.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli Are you looking for this: **303.4.** Some enchantments have the subtype “Aura.” An Aura enters the battlefield attached to an object or player. What an Aura can be attached to is defined by its enchant keyword ability (see rule 702.5, “Enchant”). Other effects can limit what a permanent can be enchanted by.

Comment: I read that and about a dozen other references.  I may just have to live with an implication short of a stated rule.  Just seems to be a gray area.  [Pacifism](http://tappedout.net/mtg-card/pacifism/) is another card that seems like it would benefit from moving where the controller wants it to.

Comment: diego's point about the rules telling you what you can do is key. There is no rule that says you can attach auras wherever you want whenever you want, just as there is no rule saying you can't just add mana to your mana pool as you like (who needs lands?). Why not just declare victory? There's no rule saying you can't do that either.

Comment: Hao Yo - the card says Enchant Creature; it doesn't say when or how.  So you are left to understanding the rules about how this occurs.  Those rules exist and that's what I was looking for.  This is moot anyway...the question has been sufficiently answered.  Perhaps a more succinct question would have been with regard to the rules for targeting, but I didn't know that when asking the original question.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli - Ah, ok. I guess it wasn't clear to some of us that the question, at heart, was about how auras work, as opposed to the narrower interpretation of "can you move auras at will".

Comment: @SteveMangiameli The Enchant keyword is defined in rule 702.5, and it doesn't do anything. It **just** restricts what types of objects the Aura can attach to.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli As diego showed, "Enchant creature" is NOT an instruction to follow. 303.4 defines what "Enchant creature" means. It doesn't mean "Pick a creature an enchant it". It is a restriction on what sort of things the aura can enchant.

Answer (score 1):

An Aura is attached to something when it enters the battlefield, and it doesn't get to move around. From the [basic rules](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf) (in the glossary):

> Aura
>
> A special type of enchantment that can be attached to a permanent. Each Aura has the keyword "enchant" followed by what it can be attached to: "enchant creature," "enchant land," and so on. When you cast an Aura spell, you choose one of the right kind of permanent to target. When the
> Aura resolves, it's put onto the battlefield attached to that permanent (it's not targeting it anymore). The Aura stays there until it's destroyed or the permanent it's attached to leaves the battlefield. If the permanent leaves the battlefield, the Aura card is put into your graveyard.

Yes, you can figure out the answer to your question from the comprehensive rules (113.1b plus the generic rules for casting a spell in 601.2, and the lack of anything in the rules that says you *can* move it around), but the basic rules are easier and quicker to understand, and you also learn a lot more in the process. For example in this case, you learned for free that auras go to the graveyard when they get detached, but from the comprehensive rules you'd have to have thought to look up state-based actions to find out. And to really verify that there wasn't something somewhere that did say they could be moved, you'd have to search/read through everything about auras.